# Trying to change IP config on Zebra printer with SGD code

Tags: zebra-printers, sgd

I am trying to configure the IP, subnet, and gateway addresses on a zebra ZT410 printer with SGD commands.
I am using the "Zebra setup utility", my *getvar* commands work, but *setvar* commands do not work. What Am I doing wrong ? My code is below...

```
! U setvar "internal_wired.ip.addr" "100.100.100.101" 
setvar "internal_wired.ip.netmask" "255.255.255.0" 
setvar "internal_wired.ip.gateway" "100.100.100.254" 
END
```

Comment: add a 1 after the U so "! U1 setvar...

Comment: Tried it, still did not change the values .